# Loading only specified links in Safari from a Cocoa (OSX, not iPhone) WebView?

Tags: objective-c, macos, webview

I've found several posts here explaining how to open *all* links within an embedded WebView in Safari (or the default browser), but I can't find anything on how you'd go about opening only links of your choosing in Safari, while the default would be for them to load in the WebView. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

You can actually load the link you click in the default browser.

For that you have to implement the `WebPolicyDecisionListener` protocol and set `policyDelegate` for the `WebView`:

```
[webView setPolicyDelegate:self];
```

And then implement the following methods:

```
-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNavigationAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request frame:(WebFrame *)frame decisionListener:(id<WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
    {

        if (WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked == [[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue])
        {
            [listener ignore];
            NSLog(@"Opening URL in browser:%@",[request URL]);
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[request URL]];

        }    
        [listener use];
    }

-(void)webView:(WebView *)webView decidePolicyForNewWindowAction:(NSDictionary *)actionInformation request:(NSURLRequest *)request newFrameName:(NSString *)frameName decisionListener:(id <WebPolicyDecisionListener>)listener
    {
        if (WebNavigationTypeLinkClicked == [[actionInformation objectForKey:WebActionNavigationTypeKey] intValue])
        {
            [listener ignore];
            NSLog(@"Opening URL new window:%@",[request URL]);
            [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openURL:[request URL]];
        }
        [listener ignore];
    }
```

This link you click will be received to this delegate methods at [request URL]

Comment: This response should be accepted. I've tested it and works perfectly fine.